# Akamai caching stratagy

Tags: caching, akamai

We started caching our static pages in akamai with user defined ttl (for example 7 days). We want control over caching so at 7th day we will purge this cache and recreate by curling all cached pages. 
The issue is as akamai serves pages from geographically near node hence there is no control/validation for cache creation. My question is,
A. How can I ensure purge happens in all nodes
B. How can I ensure while curling urls, cache is updated in all nodes.
C. Is there any better way of controlling cache in akamai?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know if you've configured a TTL in Akamai cache, the elements in cache become stale after the defined period & when a request comes on to that node once after the cache has become stale, it will hit the origin / its parent node (if the server is a child) to refresh the stale content. You don't have to explicitly CURL a URL to refresh it. Alternately if you want to forcibly refresh a cache, you can use Akamai APIs or the Edgesuite interface to manually refresh a cache.